# Error 'str' object has no attribute 'is_stale'

Tags: uber-api

After calling this method it shows me this error 'str' object has no attribute 'is_stale': response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)

this is source code:

```
import sys from uber_rides.session 
import Session from uber_rides.client 
import UberRidesClient


session = Session(oauth2credential='[redacted]')
client = UberRidesClient(session)

response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mhv/Projects/Other/Python/Uber/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uber_rides/client.py", line 128, in get_products
    return self._api_call('GET', 'v1.2/products', args=args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uber_rides/client.py", line 96, in _api_call
    self.refresh_oauth_credential()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uber_rides/client.py", line 720, in refresh_oauth_credential
    if credential.is_stale():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_stale'
```

Best regards

Comment: Please don’t post your api keys! You should regenerate it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've regenerated it and I add the traceback.